# How to get Internet Explorer 11 updates release notes

Tags: internet-explorer-11

I am searching for release notes for IE 11's different updates, that I could check what they have fixed in different versions of IE 11. 
I Googled a lot, but I couldn't get any useful results.

 Please help me out.

 Thanks!

Comment: I am testing a web application on two different versions of IE 11. In older version of IE 11 (11.0.9600.16428), its not working properly. But in IE 11 (11.0.9600.18059) it is working properly.

Comment: You should directly ask Microsoft. I think, this is your best chance.

Comment: @try-catch-finally, I think this is best idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the release notes for your current version of IE11 by following these steps:

1. Open IE11.
2. Click on the **settings cog icon** in the upper right hand corner.
3. Click **About Internet Explorer**.
4. On this page you will find a KB article link: [image: IE11 KB Article]
5. Click on that link to open the release notes.

As of 8/7/2017, the latest update is 11.0.44 and the direct link to the release notes can be **[found here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4025252/cumulative-security-update-for-internet-explorer-july-11-2017)**.

It seems that Microsoft rolls out fairly regular updates to IE11. Even though the releases are typically titled "cumulative security update", they often include other bug fixes unrelated to security.

I've been able to locate the details on prior releases with the following Google search: *site:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/ Cumulative security update for Internet Explorer*

Answer (score 0):

I have searched a lot on MSDN for Internet Explorer Release notes but couldn't able to find, only I got the release versions information. I have to contact help desk of Microsoft for Release notes.

Comment: Can you share what you've found?

Comment: @karliwson : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/969393/information-about-internet-explorer-versions

Comment: It was not helpful for me by the way... @karliwson